# Restricted maximum likelihood for mixed models

Tags: statistics, regression, maximum-likelihood

We have the following mixed model:
$$y=X\beta+Zu+\epsilon $$,
where $u \sim \mathcal{N}(0,\tau I_d)$ and $\epsilon \sim \mathcal{N}(0,\sigma I_p)$. When using restricted maximum likelihood for mixed models (REML), we use some matrix W which has the propriety that $WX=0$, then we can just calculate the maximum likelihood of
$$ Wy=WX \beta+WZu+W\epsilon=WZu+W\epsilon$$
to find $\tau$ and $\sigma$ and then we can get $\beta$ by maximum likelihood using the previous reults. But I don't understand why we don't we use another approach where we just choose W such that it "kills" the variance term Z. In other terms, we want $WZ=0$ so that we can solve by maximum likelihood:
$$Wy=WX\beta+W\epsilon$$ and use maximum likelihood to find $\beta$ and $\sigma$ and then use those results to find $\tau$. I find the second approach more intuitive but from the sources I read they don't even mention the second approach so I assume there must be a good reason for that. If there is good reason for that, what would it be?

Comment: You should move your questions to cross-validated stackexchange as they can provide more insight into this type of questions.

Comment: How can I do this ? From what I understood I need a lot of reputation to do it.

Comment: Copy and paste your question to there; then delete this question.